# How do I update attachment content with the google sites python API?

Tags: python, gdata-api, google-sites

I'm trying to write a script that will automatically update some attachments on a website created and managed through Google Sites.  This should be possible as Google released the [Sites API](http://code.google.com/apis/sites/) in September and the [Python GData API](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) claims to support sites.  However, the closest method I can find is called `client.update`, which allows me to update the metadata of an attachment, but not the content.

In the Java API updating an attachment is done by creating a new `MediaFileSource` and then calling `entry.setMediaFileSource(source)` followed by `entry.updateMedia()`.  However, I can't find anything similar in the Python API.  Am I dumb and just missing something, or is it really not possible to update a google sites attachment using the python API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sites api has been updated to v1.1; this is probably a new addition

http://code.google.com/apis/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#UpdatingContent

Comment: We have a winner, although their guide is slightly incorrect.   Rather than using `entry.content.text = "YOUR NEW HTML"` you need to use `entry.content = atom.data.Content("YOUR NEW HTML")`, otherwise it just prepends the data.  Your pointer was incredibly helpful in figuring this out.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python#UpdatingContent) provides an example on how to update an attachment's content and metadata (subsection Replacing an attachment's content and metadata)

The only thing left out is to get `existing_attachment` which can be done easily with something like this:

```
existing_attachment = None
uri = '%s?kind=%s' % (client.MakeContentFeedUri(), 'attachment')
feed = client.GetContentFeed(uri=uri)
for entry in feed.entry:
  if entry.title.text == title:
    print '%s [%s]' % (entry.title.text, entry.Kind())
    existing_attachment = entry
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the API there is weird, and the documentation is not very clear. Here is what I have figured out. First time you upload an attachment, you do it through UploadAttachment method, but on the follow-up attempts, you need to call Update. Here's the code that does it:

```
class AttachmentUploader(object):
  """Uploads a given attachment to a given filecabinet in Google Sites."""

  def __init__(self, site, username, password):
    self.client = gdata.sites.client.SitesClient(
        source="uploaderScript", site=site)
    self.client.ssl = True
    try:
      self.client.ClientLogin(username, password, "some.key")
    except:
      traceback.print_exc()
      raise

  def FindAttachment(self, title):
    uri = "%s?kind=%s" % (self.client.MakeContentFeedUri(), "attachment")
    feed = self.client.GetContentFeed(uri=uri)
    for entry in feed.entry:
      if entry.title.text == title:
        return entry
    return None

  def FindCabinet(self, title):
    uri = "%s?kind=%s" % (self.client.MakeContentFeedUri(), "filecabinet")
    feed = self.client.GetContentFeed(uri=uri)
    for entry in feed.entry:
      if entry.title.text == title:
        return entry
    return None

  def Upload(self, cabinet_title, title, file_path, description):
    """Upload the given file as attachment."""
    ms = gdata.data.MediaSource(file_path=file_path, content_type="text/ascii")

    existing_attachment = self.FindAttachment(title)
    if existing_attachment is not None:
      existing_attachment.summary.text = description
      updated = self.client.Update(existing_attachment, media_source=ms)
      print "Updated: ", updated.GetAlternateLink().href
    else:
      cabinet = self.FindCabinet(cabinet_title)
      if cabinet is None:
        print "OUCH: cabinet %s does not exist" % cabinet_title
        return
      attachment = self.client.UploadAttachment(
          ms, cabinet, title=title, description=description)
      print "Uploaded: ", attachment.GetAlternateLink().href
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed class to help out. The original problem was that the API didn't support updating attachments at the time. You still get points because this will be really helpful for folks looking for an implementation in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [upload_attachment](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/gdata.sites.client.html#SitesClient-upload_attachment) method, that should work. You may also want to check out the [sample code](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/trunk/samples/sites/sites_example.py) for Sites API, it uses that method.

Comment: Unfortunately, while that works for uploading an attachment, it doesn't allow one to update an attachment, which is what I need to do.  Calling `upload_attachment` with a duplicate filename returns the error:
    Server responded with: 409, Duplicate insert - node with name &quot;test.txt&quot; already exists - existing node id is 4770556649999999999

Comment: I think the only way is to use how Java library does: http://code.google.com/apis/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UpdatingAnAttachment

Current Python library code use gdata protocol, which is undocumented. The workaround it the get the ClientLogin authorization from gdata client and make http request via PUT method on your own. Or delete the old file and upload new one, which is very awful.

Comment: My impression is that the Java library also uses the GData protocol.  So, from the sounds of it, it's not really possible to do in Python right now.  I've thought about delete and re-add, but that's really awful and can mangle some links.  Maybe I just need to wait a while...